# How to change variables of a probability distribution when variables have different dimensions

Tags: probability-distributions

Is this even possible?  Say I have a pdf $p(x,y\mid\phi)$, and a function $z = f(x,y)$.  Is there a way to derive $p(z\mid\phi)$?  The usual change of variables rule

$$p(z\mid\phi) = p(x,y\mid\phi) ~\left \lvert \frac{d(x,y)}{dz} \right \rvert$$

doesn't seem to help, as the Jacobian is not square and hence no Jacobian determinant.